# Does Blogger get a site better rankings for being owned by Google?

Tags: seo, google, search-engine-indexing, blogger, blogspot

given that I want to create a blog and purchase my own domain:

The fact that **Blogger** is provided by **Google**, may it imply a higher **indexing** performance, compared both to the other weblog publishing tools (like Wordpress, Tumblr...) and creating a website fom scratch?

Comment: no... blogger does not benefit from any sort secret squirrel SEO. If your question was directed at YouTube then it'd be a whole different outcome.

Answer (score 3):

Indexing performance? I wouldn't bother measuring it unless you end up having your own site with **quality content** (including lots of text) that people actually want to see. It doesn't matter if you use "Blogger" or wordpress or any other thing that aids you in writing content. **What matters the most is the content**

If by performance you mean speed, you have little control. Make a website with quality content, sign up for "webmaster tools" accounts with bing, google (google calls theirs the "search console") and other search engines you want your site indexed in, then configure the crawl rate in each to maximum.

Then for "maximum performance", publish your quality site, scan it with a bunch of SEO tools like webpagetest.org then the search engines might index your site like crazy. Its also good to have a sitemap to your site to submit to search engines to help them discover all the URLs including those that aren't linked from anywhere else.

Comment: I think by "indexing performance" he means faster indexing and better rankings